# How to use a UICollectionViewController's custom initializer with UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

Let's say you wanted to use a custom initializer to instantiate `UICollectionViewController`.

With `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, it's straightforward:

```swift
init() {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    super.init(collectionViewLayout: layout)
}
```

But, `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`'s designated initializers require a few parameters, most importantly the section parameter:

```swift
UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section:, configuration:)
// or 
UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(sectionProvider:, configuration:)
```

This means I have to create the entire layout within the custom initializer of `UICollectionViewController`. If the layout incorporates things like enum as a section identifier, that has to be in the initializer as well.  If you have to include `NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment` in your layout, it also becomes problematic.

```swift
init() {
    let item = /..
    let group = /..
    let section = /..
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
    super.init(collectionViewLayout: layout)
}
```

I'm looking at the Apple's [examples](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views) and all of them use `UIViewController` instead of `UICollectionViewController` by default. Even though the examples don't use any custom initializers, this method does get around the aforementioned problem by allowing us to create the layout afterwards:

```swift
var collectionView: UICollectionView! = nil
collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: createLayout())
```

You can now simply use the `UIViewController`'s custom initializer.

What is the best way to use `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` with a custom initializer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be over-thinking this. There is absolutely no law preventing you from *changing* the layout assigned to a collection view; its `collectionViewLayout` property is assignable at any time.

So just assign a "dummy" layout to the collection view controller in the initializer, and then do the real creation and assignment of the layout in `viewDidLoad` just as you normally would.

Just to give a common use case: how would you create a collection view controller in the storyboard if you wanted to use a compositional layout? What I do is give the collection view in the storyboard a flow layout. Then in `viewDidLoad` I create the real layout (the compositional layout) in code and assign it to `self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout`, and no harm done.